# Why does my program not respond when I run it

Tags: python, windows, zelle-graphics

I recently started python, and realize this is probably a dumb question to be asking, but I was trying to make a choice based game using a window. I used `graphics.py` to display my text. When I run the code, the window opens but is in the "not responding state", and I couldn't find out what was wrong.
also there was no error code

I basically copied everything from a video from left peel. However, is vids are very outdated so there is probably an error somewhere, but there are no more sites or vids that explain `graphics.py`

Here is the code:

```
from graphics import *


def main():
    win = GraphWin("win", 1300, 700)
    #win.setBackground(color_rgb(255, 0, 0))

    txt = Text(Point(650, 120), 'This was text')
    txt1 = Text(Point(650, 135), "This was text")
    txt2 = Text(Point(650, 150), "This was text")
    txt3 = Text(Point(650, 165), "This was text")
    txt4 = Text(Point(650, 180), "This was text "
                                 "This was text.")

    img = Image(Point(650, 450), "a picture (.gif)")
    nxt = Text(Point(1090, 590), "Type next for next")
    txt.draw(win)
    txt1.draw(win)
    txt2.draw(win)
    txt3.draw(win)
    txt4.draw(win)

    img.draw(win)
    inputb = Entry(Point(1200, 590), 10)
    inputb.draw(win)
    nxt.draw(win)

    s = inputb.getText()

    command = inputb.getText()
    while True:
        s = inputb.getText()
        if s == 'next':
            the program stopped working from here, so i just put a print("")

main()
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an error. In the code, the " is there

Comment: Take a look on the second warning of this link, and tell me if that carifies you something; http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite siting atop tkinter, Zelle Graphics has no user access to the event manager!  (Unlike Python turtle which also sits atop tkinter.)  And the `Entry` object really exposes this shortcomming.

Two ways people make it have any *state* is to either run an infinite loop processing input constantly or use mouse clicks to advance the state.  Since you're getting the "not responding" message, I assume you're running under some sort of development IDE, like Anaconda, and it does not like your runaway `while True:` loop.  So we need to switch to mouse clicks.  Here's a simple example:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin()

entry = Entry(Point(100, 100), 10)
entry.draw(win)

text = Text(Point(100, 150), 'This is text')
text.draw(win)

while True:
    win.getMouse()

    string = entry.getText()

    if string.lower() == 'quit':
        break

    text.setText(string.upper())
```

You can type in the `Entry` widget, and then when you click the mouse, your input will show up in the `Text` widget, but in all upper case.  If you enter "quit", the program will exit.  Your user needs to know to click after any input into any entry field.